# Grep: get first char/symbol from the line outputs of the git status -s

Tags: git, unix, grep

This command is:

```
while read -r line
do
    modfied="$line"
    echo "Found: $modfied"
done < <(git status -s | grep "M " | awk '{if ($1 == "M") print $2}' | grep --file=.git/ForGeneratingSBConfigAlert.txt --fixed-strings)
```

It prints out line by line results of the `git status -s` command and gets the 'M' symbol with the space after (means that file has been modified). But I want it to match the first symbol of the command output only and output the full line if the first symbols matches one of these: M, A, D, R, C. The second symbol can be every other symbol, even space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `^` at the beginning of your pattern. This symbol matches at the beginning of the line.

```
... | grep '^M ' | ...
```

Incidentally, you could fold that into the `awk` command by using the pattern `/^M /` in your `awk` program - that would considerably simplify your shell pipeline.

```
... | awk '/^M / {print $2}' | ...
```

Comment: So to be clear: do you want to ask how to change your `grep` command so that it matches any of several characters, not only `M`? Or do you want to ask how to change it to ignore the second character in the line? Or something else?

Comment: thsi worked fine for me: `git status -s | grep -E "^M|^D|^A|^R|^C" | awk '{if ($1 == "M" || $1 == "D" || $1 == "A" || $1 == "R" || $1 == "C") print $2}' | grep --file=.git/ForGeneratingSBConfigAlert.txt --fixed-strings`

Comment: But I don't know how to make awk work if, for exmp afer "M", there is any symbol(even space)

Comment: Man, please help me. I am admitting I dont know how to use google. Look at this line:  `awk '{if ($1 == "M") print $2}'`. How can I make it search for any char after "M", even if it is space?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean by "search for any char"? Do you want to select lines that start with M followed by any other character, i.e. any line of length 2 or more that starts with M? Or lines of length 2 or more that start with one of MDARC? Or lines that start with one of MDARC and contain a specific character later in the line? (which one?) Or do you want to select lines that start with one of MDARC and search for a specific character in the rest of the line and print it? Or something else?

Comment: For search one of MDARC chars followed by any char, even space.
Exmp: after searching for string `MM test.txt` sed/awl must give the output string `test.txt`(not the content of the file, but just this string as I have written). Is it possible through awk? If not, do you know how to make this happen in sed?

Comment: So again, to check if I understand correctly: you want to search for lines starting with any of MDARC, and then print the second word in the line? If so, why did you put a space after the `M` in your original `grep` command?

Comment: Where? I am trying to do something like this: `git status -s | grep -E "^M|^D|^A|^R|^C" | awk '{if ($1~/D / || $1~/D./)  print $2}'`. The chars after M(for example) must be, lets say , M or A or D or space

Comment: In the question you wrote `grep "M "`. I'm wondering why you included the space after `M`? Also, now are you saying the second character in the line has to be something specific? Or does it just have to be either the same as the first character, or a space?

Comment: In question it was example, that I have already rewriten. I want something like that: `git status -s | grep -E "^M" | awk '{if ($1~/M\s/ || $1~/M\S/)  print $2}'`

Comment: This command just can't find space after M. It works with output from the console `M  file.name`

Comment: Oh, FOUND IT. It's a + sign after the char. I will update my status

Comment: `git status -s | grep -E "^M|^D|^A|^R|^C" | awk '{if ($1~/M+/ || $1~/D+/ || $1~/A+/ || $1~/R+/ || $1~/C+/) print $2}' | grep --file=.git/ForGeneratingSBConfigAlert.txt --fixed-strings`